# How do you check whether every word in one string is found in another string?

Tags: java, string

Let's say I have a book title and I search for it in a database. The database produces matches, some of which are full matches and some of which are partial matches.

**A `full match` is when every word in the search result is represented by a word in the search terms.** `(i.e. there does not have to be a complete overlap on both sides)`

*I am only concerned with finding the full matches.*

So if I type a search for `"Ernest Hemingway - The Old Man and the Sea"` and the results return the following:

```
Charles Nordhoff - Men Against The Sea
Rodman Philbrick - The Young Man and the Sea
Ernest Hemingway - The Old Man and the Sea
Ernest Hemingway - The Sun Also Rises
Ernest Hemingway - A Farewell to Arms
Ernest Hemingway - For Whom the Bell Tolls
Ernest Hemingway - A Moveable Feast
Ernest Hemingway - True at First Light
Men Against The Sea
The Old Man and the Sea
The Old Man and the Sea Dog
```

There are **TWO** `full matches` in this list: (according to the definition above)

```
Ernest Hemingway - The Old Man and the Sea 
The Old Man and the Sea
```

To do this in Java, assume I have two variables:

```
String searchTerms;
List<String> searchResults;
```

`searchTerms` in the example above represents what I typed in: `Ernest Hemingway - The Old Man and the Sea`

`searchResults` represents the list of strings I got back from the database above.

```
for (String result : searchResults) {
  // How to check for a full match? 
  // (each word in `result` is found in `searchTerms` 
}
```

**My question is: in this `for-loop`, how do I check whether every word in the `result` String has a corresponding word in the `searchTerms` String?**

Answer (score 3):

To find the full match as you have defined it, you want to test that a set of tokens contains a particular subset.  You can do this easily using a [Set](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) which you get for free in the collections libraries.  One way to do this would be (the expense of regexes aside):

```
   Set<String> searchTerms = new HashSet<String>();
   Set<String> resultTokens = new HashSet<String>();

   searchTerms.addAll( Arrays.asList( searchString.split( "\\s+" ) );

   for ( String result : searchResults )
   {
      resultTokens.clear();
      resultTokens.addAll( Arrays.asList( result.split( "\\s+" ) ) );
      if ( resultTokens.containsAll( searchTerms ) )
      {
         // Perform match code
      }
   }
```

Alternatively, if you wanted to be stricter about it, you could test for set equality using resultTokens.equals( searchTerms ).  In your example, this would narrow the result set to "Ernest Hemingway - The Old Man and the Sea"

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your database result is accurate,

Split up `result` into tokens (words) using `String.split(String delimiter)` and see whether each token is found in `searchTerms` (using `searchTerms.indexOf(String word) == -1`).

```
for (String result : searchResults) {
    for(String word : result) {
        if(searchTerms.indexOf(word) == -1) {
            // result is not a full match
        }
    }

    //If none of the if statements executed, statement is a full match.
}
```